# what is the ebean model class for mysql one to one relationship tables with both table has auto increment id

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two tables with one-to-one relationship :

```
create table customer(
    customer_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
    customer_name varchar;
    ...
)
```

And :

```
create table customer_login(
    customer_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
    password varchar;
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`)
)
```

Now, I want save customer and customer_login same time(customer first then customer_login). How I should create customer_id in both model class using ebean in play framework

Comment: A little effort on presentation and searching would be nice before posting here.

Comment: Thanks.But I tried in google. question is same time after saving customer I have to save customer_login with same id. anyway I am using play for only last 7 days.